# The meaning of よう in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The meaning of よう in this sentence?

> 先生に相談したところ、ぜひ大学院に行く**よう**勧められた。

I assume that it introduces the advice, but it shouldn't be a particle or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Its an abbreviation of ように.
In Chinese characters its 様に.
So its a noun.
ように is like "in the manner of".
よう/様 is like "manner"/"way".